# Kill All Running Apps

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am developing an app for iOS and I want to have a button that, if pressed, kills all other application currently running in the background of the users device.

```
-(IBAction)killAppsButton:(id)sender{
```

//what code do I put here for the button to accomplish this??

}.

Comment: Perhaps you can try executing a memory intensive operation so that other apps will quit when the iOS system is overtaxed.

Comment: Do you know `kill` function? Being outside sandbox with root privileges you can kill any process with it. All you have to do is find process IDs of the processes you want to kill.

Comment: Just turn off the power.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. Apps on iOS are sandboxed and therefore cannot kill each other.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this app is for jailbroken iOS devices. How do tweaks such as switch spring accomplish this??